# Refresh ListView Items upon button triggered

Tags: java, android, listview

I was having some problem when trying to refresh the items in list view after the button was triggered. Here is how I populate the listview onCreate:

```
public class EventChat extends Fragment {
Context context;
View eventChat;

String userID, eventID;

private ListView listview;
public ArrayList<EventComment> _commentlist = new ArrayList<EventComment>();
TextView txtDisplayCommentBy, txtDisplayDateTime, txtDisplayCommentDesc,
        txtEventChat;

Button btnChatSubmit;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    eventChat = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_chat, container, false);
    context = getActivity();

    listview = (ListView) eventChat.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    txtEventChat = (TextView) eventChat.findViewById(R.id.txtEventChat);

    btnChatSubmit = (Button) eventChat.findViewById(R.id.btnChatSubmit);
    btnChatSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onSubmitChatClicked();
        }
    });

    Intent i = getActivity().getIntent();
    _commentlist = (ArrayList<EventComment>) i
            .getSerializableExtra("eventCommentObj");
    Event eventModel = (Event) i.getSerializableExtra("eventObj");

    userID = "Gab";
    eventID = eventModel.getEventID();

    listview.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(getActivity()));

    return eventChat;
}

private class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public ListAdapter(Context context) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return _commentlist.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.eventchat_listview_row,
                    null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.txt_dcommentBy = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayCommentBy);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.txt_dcommentBy.setText(_commentlist.get(position)
                .getCommentBy().trim());
        return convertView;
    }
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_dcommentBy;
    TextView txt_ddateTime;
    TextView txt_dcommentDesc;
}
}
```

When my button was triggered and insert a new record into database, at the same time, I wanted the list view items to be refreshed:

```
public void onSubmitChatClicked() {
    EventComment commentModel = new EventComment();
    String currentDate = EventDateTime.getCurrentDate();
    String currentTime = EventDateTime.getCurrentTime();
    String commentDesc = String.valueOf(txtEventChat.getText());
    commentModel.setCommentBy(userID);
    commentModel.setEventID(eventID);
    commentModel.setCommentDate(currentDate);
    commentModel.setCommentTime(currentTime);
    commentModel.setCommentDesc(commentDesc);
    new CreateCommentAsyncTask(context).execute(commentModel);

    txtEventChat.setText("");

}
```

However, it does not refresh. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`? in button click at last after data is saved?

Comment: But what is the adapter data type?

Comment: Your listview 's adapter.

Comment: @MysticMagic Is it listview.notifyDataSetChanged()? But with this, I am getting error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this looks pretty straightforward.

First make your adapter a class member, so you can access it later:

```
private ListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity();
    listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    ...
}
```

Then, when you submit the item, also add it to your ArrayList and update your adapter:

```
public void onSubmitChatClicked() {
    EventComment commentModel = new EventComment();
    String currentDate = EventDateTime.getCurrentDate();
    String currentTime = EventDateTime.getCurrentTime();
    String commentDesc = String.valueOf(txtEventChat.getText());
    commentModel.setCommentBy(userID);
    commentModel.setEventID(eventID);
    commentModel.setCommentDate(currentDate);
    commentModel.setCommentTime(currentTime);
    commentModel.setCommentDesc(commentDesc);

    // Add the new element to your DB
    new CreateCommentAsyncTask(context).execute(commentModel);
    // Add the new element to your current ArrayList
    _commentlist.add(commentModel)
    // Update theListView, by updating the adapter
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    txtEventChat.setText("");
}
```

EDIT:

Little more explanation:

When your fragment is created you are passed an array of `EventComment` items. I guess these are the elements from your DB. When you update the database, however, your ArrayList won't get updated, unless you reload the whole fragment. That's why you add the item to the DB, and to the list manually, and with `notifyDataSetChanged`, you force your adapter to update the ListView.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. But could you help me to clarify is it work in this way: when the button was triggered, it will add the new record into the static _commentlist and the notifyDataSetChanged of adapter will refresh the list view?

Comment: @IWasSoLost see my answer update for a little more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do `listview.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(getActivity()));` to achieve this. You should create an instance of `adapter` and call `adapter.add` + `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`

This is a very good tutorial :

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html

Comment: Sorry but would you mind to show me code examples? Because I  don't quite get it

Comment: @IWasSoLost Done :) You might need to do some googling, like "listview adapter android" because you need to understand how adapter work

Comment: So can I assumed that I've to refractor all my codes to implement the adapter?

Comment: @IWasSoLost Do you mean you need to change a lot of code? It depends on what you are going to do with `listview`. Just a friendly suggestion,`adapter` is basic thing in android which you should understand...

Comment: Would you mind to guide me by providing me some solutions to implement into my situation? Because I tried to change and everything turned red :(

Comment: @IWasSoLost im afraid the code needed for that is too much (its hard to code just in chrome). Do you want to create a list of `commentModel`? So your `listview` showing date, time and desc?

Comment: But what can I do with the list of commentModel?